# How to implement an oblique decision tree for regression?

Tags: decision-trees

There are numerous ways to induce an oblique decision tree in the decision tree induction domain, such as using a support vector machine to determine the best hyper-plane. However, is it possible to generate an oblique decision tree for regression? I discovered that the majority of existing literature has omitted this issue. By the way, is there an open-source machine learning tool that already includes an oblique tree for regression?